# Mongodb secondary going down

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, aws, mongodb-3.6

I have a problem with my secondary, which is constantly going down, in normal replica set (primary, secondary, arbiter).

What I saw while investigating that there is one long lasting operation in database which is connected to sync with master:

```
{
    "host" : "primary-ip:my-port",
    "desc" : "WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs",
    "threadId" : "140599714879232",
    "active" : true,
    "currentOpTime" : "2018-04-24T09:36:40.103+0000",
    "opid" : 9222195,
    "secs_running" : NumberLong(30849),
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("30849456103"),
    "op" : "none",
    "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
    "command" : {

    },
    "numYields" : 0,
    "locks" : {

    },
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "lockStats" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One other thing that I saw is that some of my queries didn't have indexes and there were some operations in currentOp() that were lasting around 10 sec. One more thing is strange graphs on mms monitoring interface (left is secondary, right is primary): [image]

Mongodb version: 3.6.0-rc3
Platform: Ubuntu 16.04
Cloud: AWS EC2
Usage: Lots of writes and updates

My question is what do you think is causing this behaviour? Is it possible that those queries without index are affecting this, and if they do, why are they affecting secondary instance and not primary? Should I just kill this long lasting operation?
Any kind of lead or advice is welcome.

Comment: ,Could you update rs.status() & rs.isMaster() from  replica set report.

Comment: please post your `mongodb.log` from all nodes during timeframe you have issues.

Comment: Did you find anything in the mongodb logs for the affected instance? What instance type do you use on aws for this secondary?